# Does it make sense to interact two uncorrelated independent variables in linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, interaction, panel-data

Should two continuous variables be correlated to include their interaction? I.e. does `y = x1 + x2 + x1x2` make sense if correlation between `x1` and `x2` is weak at -0.1, and their coefficients in the regression have opposite signs (`x1` β1 close to +1 and `x2` β2 close to -1)?

And if the estimated coefficient on `x1x2` is then +3, does this effectively mean the total effect of `x2` is actually positive (with β3 = +3 offsetting β2 = -1), thus both variables have a net positive association with y?

Lastly, if trying to represent this with scatter plots like `pairs(y x1 x2 x1x2)` in r, wouldn't individual and time fixed effects (panel data) make any relationship impossible to see visually?

Thanks!

Comment: "correlated" should be removed from the title since independent implies uncorrelated

Comment: @TrungDung I disagree. While lack of correlation is implied by independent, one could be interested in variables that are uncorrelated but dependent. It is up to Junlei to decide on the question to ask.

Comment: I think a linguistic issue is that in regression of a model $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\epsilon$, you have $X_1$ and $X_2$ called independent variables even if they are not independent of each other (and clearly not of $Y$)

Answer (score 11):

Definitely!

```r
set.seed(2022)
N <- 10
x1 <- rep(c(0, 1), N) # (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
x2 <- c(rep(0, N), rep(1, N)) # (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
x12 <- x1 * x2 # interaction between x1 and x2
#
y <- x1 - x2 + 5*x12 + rnorm(length(x1))
```

In this example, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent (not just uncorrelated) and have opposite signs in the regression model. However, the interaction term is important. Compare the $R^2$ or adjusted $R^2$ your models have when you regress on just $x_1$ and $x_2$ versus regressing on those variables plus their interaction.

Comment: What do you mean by "independent (not just uncorrelated)" here?  I know the term "independent" only for random variables, but not for data.

Comment: @jochen By looking at either `x1` or `x2`, you get absolutely no insight into the other.

Comment: @jochen I think Dave means that the joint distribution of $x_1$ and $x_2$ is just the product of their marginal distributions.

Answer (score 5):

To slightly add to Dave's +1 answer, recall that omitting a regressor from a regression model will not affect the remaining coefficients (something that I would argue is more relevant and less trivial than a "better" (higher) $R^2$, which will always obtain with additional regressors - although Dave of course also points to adjusted $R^2$) if it's uncorrelated (orthogonal) with the remaining regressors.

To see this, write the OLS estimate containing two blocks of regressors $X_1$ and $X_2$ (in our example, $X_1$ could consist of `x^2` and $X_2$ of `x1` and `x2`) as
$$
\hat\beta=\begin{pmatrix}X_1'X_1&X_1'X_2\\
X_2'X_1&X_2'X_2\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}X_1'y\\
X_2'y\end{pmatrix}
$$
That is, if the two blocks are orthogonal ($X_1'X_2=0$), we obtain
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat\beta&=&\begin{pmatrix}X_1'X_1&0\\
0&X_2'X_2\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}X_1'y\\
X_2'y\end{pmatrix}\\
&=&\begin{pmatrix}(X_1'X_1)^{-1}&0\\
0&(X_2'X_2)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X_1'y\\
X_2'y\end{pmatrix}\\
&=&\begin{pmatrix}(X_1'X_1)^{-1}X_1'y\\
(X_2'X_2)^{-1}X_2'y\end{pmatrix},
\end{eqnarray*}
i.e. the coefficients of two separate regressions.

Now, in Dave's example, the interaction has its own partial effect (equal to 5), and, while `x1` and `x2` *are* uncorrelated, `x12` is *not* uncorrelated with `x1` nor `x2`. I slightly extend Dave's example:

```
set.seed(2022)
N <- 10
x1 <- rep(c(0, 1), N) # (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
x2 <- c(rep(0, N), rep(1, N)) # (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
x12 <- x1 * x2 # interaction between x1 and x2
#
y <- x1 - x2 + 5*x12 + rnorm(length(x1))

lm.int <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x12)
lm.wo.int <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
summary(lm.int)
summary(lm.wo.int)

cor(x1, x2)  # zero
cor(x12, x2) # not zero
cor(x12, x1) # not zero
```