Interaction terms in logistic regression model of patient mortality
Admittedly, I am a bit inexperienced in the world of statistics and data modeling but am trying my best to learn on the job. As a first time user, I apologize if there are any formatting errors here!
I am attempting to create a binary logistic regression model in R in order to determine which variables have the strongest influence in determining mortality in patients infected with a pathogen. My main question is whether a positive or negative antibody response is important in impacting mortality when considered next to traditionally important clinical indicators of mortality. The sample size is around 300. The variables are as follows:

Outcome: Mortality (yes or no)
Antibody response (a=pos, b=neg); variable is named "typeABC"
Age
CD4 cell count
IV Drug Use (yes or no)
Treatment (Medicine 1 or Medicine 2)
Geography (North or South)
Fungal burden

Here is the result of the model, without interaction terms. Antibody response is significant, which makes sense with the data (90+% of patients who died did not mount a specific antibody response, compared with 60% of surviving patients).
Call:
glm(formula = evdeath_24w ~ typeABC + age + cd4_bl + ivdu + treatment + 
    geography + log10_fungal_count_bl, family = binomial, data = master2)

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -9.128814   1.947757  -4.687 2.77e-06 ***
typeABCb               2.120532   1.073605   1.975   0.0483 *  
age                    0.066931   0.032178   2.080   0.0375 *  
cd4_bl                -0.002845   0.012082  -0.236   0.8138    
ivduYes                0.813125   0.621696   1.308   0.1909    
treatmentitra          1.195186   0.582436   2.052   0.0402 *  
geographysouth         1.643722   0.671547   2.448   0.0144 *  
log10_fungal_count_bl  0.065280   0.182710   0.357   0.7209    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 130.27  on 296  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 106.74  on 289  degrees of freedom
  (18 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 122.74

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7

I am having trouble determining which interaction terms to include. After some EDA, it is apparent that some of the variables are associated with each other. Should I only include the interaction terms that are associated with each other in the model? Ex: CD4 count and drug use are associated via Wilcoxon. Here is the result of including only these interaction terms:
Call:
glm(formula = evdeath_24w ~ typeABC + age + cd4_bl + ivdu + treatment + 
    geography + log10_fungal_count_bl + cd4_bl * ivdu + cd4_bl * 
    treatment + cd4_bl * geography + typeABC * log10_fungal_count_bl + 
    typeABC * treatment + typeABC * geography, family = binomial, 
    data = master2)

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                    -2.262e+01  2.660e+03  -0.009   0.9932  
typeABCb                        1.477e+01  2.660e+03   0.006   0.9956  
age                             6.946e-02  3.291e-02   2.110   0.0348 *
cd4_bl                          2.316e-02  4.674e-02   0.495   0.6203  
ivduYes                         2.044e+00  9.095e-01   2.248   0.0246 *
treatmentitra                   1.657e+01  2.660e+03   0.006   0.9950  
geographysouth                 -1.636e+01  2.528e+03  -0.006   0.9948  
log10_fungal_count_bl          -9.252e-02  7.954e-01  -0.116   0.9074  
cd4_bl:ivduYes                 -1.124e-01  7.634e-02  -1.473   0.1408  
cd4_bl:treatmentitra           -2.950e-02  2.608e-02  -1.131   0.2581  
cd4_bl:geographysouth           4.977e-03  4.174e-02   0.119   0.9051  
typeABCb:log10_fungal_count_bl  1.711e-01  8.138e-01   0.210   0.8335  
typeABCb:treatmentitra         -1.494e+01  2.660e+03  -0.006   0.9955  
typeABCb:geographysouth         1.827e+01  2.528e+03   0.007   0.9942  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 130.27  on 296  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  98.95  on 283  degrees of freedom
  (18 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 126.95

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 19

The result of this model doesn't seem to make sense to me. I have considered including interaction terms that theoretically influence one another, but in theory, many of these variables are linked (ex: drug use reduces T helper cell count, aging broadly impacts humoral response and therefore possibly antibody production, drug use may be higher in geographic southern part of country corresponding with higher population density and larger cities, etc); hence why I tried only including those that are statistically associated via Wilcoxon, Chi squared, or Pearson. I am hoping someone can help guide me. Thank you very much!

Welcome to CV, Badger.  You can find a lot of material here by searching for your key terms like "interaction." Important related topics are model determination, variable selection, and overfitting.   It might help to realize that interactions (which concern predicting a response) are a completely different concept from, and mathematically distinct from, associations among those explanatory variables (which concern only those variables themselves and therefore have nothing at all to do with the response).

Generally adding interaction terms of already correlated predictors makes things worse, as it worsens the multicolinearity problem, reduces your d.f, etc. Note that interaction and correlation are completely different (e.g. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564744/does-it-make-sense-to-interact-two-uncorrelated-independent-variables-in-linear). If anything, you should test interactions of uncorrelated predictors. But first read this very good answer  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564744/does-it-make-sense-to-interact-two-uncorrelated-independent-variables-in-linear.

The principal reason for including interactions (or not doing so) should be that these interactions make sense from a substantive point of view or that you are interested in exploring them, not whether they are correlated or not.
An interaction means that the relationship between one IV and the DV is different at different levels of another IV. So, for example, do you think that the relationship of CD4 count to mortality might be different at different ages?
If they are correlated, then the interaction may introduce colinearity, which causes other problems. One way to try to cope with this is to center the variables before taking the product.
